# Display list data into public facing site

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, content-query-web-part, publishing-page

I am building a publishing site with a home page that has a carousel/slider, quick links, latest news and upcoming events.

The slider and links will be stored in lists that the site author can manage. The news and events will be pages stored in a news site (no blog, just simple) and events site.

The design is very custom, much like the sites that are on topsharepoint.com.

Is the best way to pull the data to have content query web parts embedded in my home page aspx, along with some custom xslt to get the exact HTML that I want outputted for each component? We are using a html/CSS framework and would like to not have sp markup where possible.

EDIT:

Would using a XsltListViewWebPart be another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you question is slightly opinion based

you can choose between [CQWP](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2010-Content-Query-Web-Part-Demistified.aspx) and [DVWP](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/07/21/content-roll-up-options-part-iii-data-view-web-part/)

CQWP should be fine, provided that you can achieve what you are looking for with it (e.g. no paging).

from your requirements, you will be able to use DVWP for more advanced scenarios

for reference, there are a few interesting alternatives:

[CQWP with paging](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/)

[Lightning Conductor](http://lightningtools.com/products/lightning-conductor-web-part-2010/) (cross site collection/web application rollup)

further reading

http://www.novolocus.com/2008/07/24/content-roll-up-options-conclusions/

[Web Parts for views and forms in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. There is no paging required, but I just want the simplest solution for displaying items from a list and to have my own custom HTML.